# mod_rewrite change extensions .gif/.jpg to .png

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The rule I have been fruitlessly working with doesn't work, I am trying to get all images in 1 directory to load as .png The images in the directory are a mixture of .png, .jpg and .gif

I want to be able to load the file tree.jpg by going to tree.png (no files have the same name). I am sure my mistake is obvious or my entire attempt is wrong, I just can't work it out.

The htaccess file is in the same folder with the images, which is called /thumbs

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.gif$ /thumbs/$1.png [R,L,NC]
```

I tried this also, but it just givens a broken link to both .gif and .png versions

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.gif$ $1.png
```

I tried this too, but it adds in my server path to the URL for some reason

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.gif$ $1.png [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: So browser sends request to `/animage.gif` and you want to internally load `/animage.png` ? Or reverse of it?

Comment: @anubhava The reverse :) browser requests /animage.png and I want to display /animage.gif instead

Comment: So <img src="animage.png"> would actually show animage.gif in the browser window

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.png$ /$1.gif [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @anubhava I tried this copy and pasted what you said but it just said file doesn't exist for the .png that were .gif :(

Comment: Ok just rout first line and retry. You have to place this in DocumentRoot as first rule.

Comment: Hey @anubhava I tried in as first rule in root htaccess, but I could not get it to work, I must have missed something :S

Comment: can you try just this edited rule and make sure it is in root .htaccess Also tell me full URL for `.png` image?